# Converting number property into words using SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, types

I am trying to convert a prop into words using this:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(lpad(123456, 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') amount,
```

This works, but I want to replace 123456 with a dynamic property.

My prop is

```
 l.unit_selling_price * shipped_qty .
```

So my query is actually

```
to_char(to_timestamp(lpad(l.unit_selling_price * shipped_qty, 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') amount,
```

This is not working. It throws an error

> date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

What may cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is decimal point character within your padded string sent to To_TimeStamp() function. There is no place for anything else but numbers. If you get ridd of that character in any way (Round() zero, Floor(), Ceil(), Cast numeric, Cast Integer) the issue will dissapear.

```sql
Select  3.3333 * 12 "NMBR", 
        Cast(3.3333 * 12 as Numeric) "CASTED_NUMERIC",
        to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(Cast(3.3333333 * 12 as Numeric), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') "CASTED_NUMERIC_AMT", 
        Round(3.3333 * 12, 0) "ROUNDED_0",
        to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(Round(3.3333333 * 12, 0), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') "ROUNDED_0_AMT",
        CEIL(3.3333 * 12) "CEILED",
        to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(CEIL(3.3333333 * 12), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') "CEILED_AMT",
        FLOOR(3.3333 * 12) "FLOORED",
        to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(FLOOR(3.3333333 * 12), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') "FLOORED_AMT",
        lpad(3.3333 * 12, 9, '0') "PADDED_NMBR"
From Dual
/*
      NMBR CASTED_NUMERIC CASTED_NUMERIC_AMT    ROUNDED_0  ROUNDED_0_AMT           CEILED CEILED_AMT         FLOORED FLOORED_AMT     PADDED_NMBR
---------- -------------- --------------------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- --------------- -----------
   39,9996             40 Forty                         40 Forty                       40 Forty                   39 Thirty-Nine     0039,9996   */
```

Whatever you choose to do with multiplication result gives the result without error and the goal is to get just numbers within string passed to To_TimeStamp() function.
When you pass the PADDED_NMBR with decimal point character (last column above) you get the error.
If this is about some currency amounts in words then one option (without rounding second decimal) could be like below

```
Select  to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(Floor(3.3333333 * 12), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') || ' Euro(s) And ' ||
        to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(SubStr(3.3333333 * 12  - Floor(3.3333333 * 12), InStr(3.3333333 * 12  - Floor(3.3333333 * 12), ',') + 1, 2), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') || ' cent(s)' "AMOUNT"
From Dual
/*
AMOUNT                                       
---------------------------------------------
Thirty-Nine Euro(s) And Ninety-Nine cent(s)   */
```

APEX tested sample (following comments)

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (Select 1207.37 "UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY", 12.3 "UNIT_SELLING_PRICE", 10.7 "SHIPPED_QTY" From Dual)
select     'Rial Omani ' || 
            to_char(to_timestamp(lpad(floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY)),9,0),'FF9'),'Ffsp') || ' and ' || 
            to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(
                                        SubStr( sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY) - Floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY)), 
                                                InStr(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY) - Floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY)), '.') + 1, 
                                                2)
                                     , 9, '0')
                    , 'FF9')
            , 'Ffsp') || ' Baizas Only'
From tbl l
/*    R e s u l t :
Rial Omani One Thousand Two Hundred Seven and Thirty-Seven Baizas Only  */
```

Comment: i edited my subquery like this : (select 'Rial Omani ' ||to_char(to_timestamp(lpad(floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE*SHIPPED_QTY)),9,0),'FF9'),'Ffsp') || ' and ' ||  to_char(to_timestamp(Lpad(SubStr(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE*SHIPPED_QTY)  - Floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE*SHIPPED_QTY)), InStr(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE*SHIPPED_QTY)  - Floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE*SHIPPED_QTY)), ',') + 1, 2), 9, '0'), 'FF9'), 'Ffsp') || ' Baizas Only'. now it works perfectly fine in toad and jasper reports. but this report is gonna show in an oracle apex application. and it still gives the same error.

Comment: @burakm In your SubStr() function there is an INSTR() function looking for comma character - try to change that comma ( ',' ) into dot ( '.' )character. Apex (think so) uses decimal point as dot. That could be a problem. I tested it on Apex puting some decimal values and got the same error with comma. After change to dot - there were no errors.

Comment: @burakm The second issue is also inside SubStr() function. You are looking for substring of  " sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY) - Floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY)) " and searching for that comma with INSTR() passing different value " sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY) - Floor(sum(l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE*SHIPPED_QTY)) " .  Compare first and second FLOOR()  function. The first takes sum of l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICESHIPPED_QTY and second sum of l.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE  *  SHIPPED_QTY

Comment: @burakm Posted APEX tested sample...

Comment: I solved it by writing a function for this and call it inside the line. But you are correct friend, these are also works. So, thank you for your time.